# Angular JS Controller to view binding not updating on window resize

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Please see the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4089/

On **window resize** if you check the **console**, `$scope.showName` keeps getting toggled between true and false as expected. However the **view does not update.** It remains with the initialized value of true.
From my understanding, the `{{}}` or `ng-bind` provides 1 way binding from controller to the view, so the value in the view should update when it changes in the controller.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$scope` only binds to the view on `$digest` cycles - your event doesn't trigger a digest cycle since there was no action taken. You have to call `$scope.$apply()` to trigger a view update.

Be warned tho, `$scope.$apply()` can throw an error if a `$digest` cycle is already in progress.

Comment: The digest already in progress will only happen if the $scope.$apply() call is wrapped in another call to $scope.$apply()

Comment: @shaunhusain -- Yeah - just letting him know though...it's a slippery slope when you start adding `$scope.$apply()` everywhere and sometimes becomes a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a call to $scope.$apply() since the event is being handled outside of an angular context you need to call $scope.$apply() to trigger a digest which will updated any watchers http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4091/

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.name = 'Timothy';
    $scope.showName = true
    $scope.nickname = 'Tim'

    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        if ($scope.showName){
            $scope.showName = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.showName = true;
        }
        console.log($scope.showName);
        $scope.$apply();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `$scope.$apply();` after any scope manipulation outside Angular events. Add it as the last statement of the `bind` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
     missing a call to $scope.$apply()
```

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4093/

Comment: I think that's the same as @shaunhusain answer

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4094/

```
$scope.$digest();
```

Try with this code.. 
I have add $digest of scope alter resize